# What's the best way to display a bunch of images from a web server in Android?

Tags: android

I need to load several thumbnails (the images on the server are full sized images, so I need to resize them in the app), and display them in a way that allows for the user to click on one (or more) and have some associated id be given back to the app for use in a larger context.

so, in pseudo code...

```
ImageObjArray ioa = loadImagesFromServer("http://server/listOfImages.php");// this returns 
for(ImageObj io : ioa){
   drawThumbnail(io); //io contains both a jpg and a reference id
}

//later when a user clicks on a thumbnail
clickHandler(){
  passIdToBundle(this.refId);
}
```

So, I've never played with a webview before but I suspect it might be the best approach here, though I don't know how easy it is to send info back out of a webview to the larger app when the user clicks on a thumbnail. Or is there a more elegant approach?

All advice welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `WebView` would be the quickest way to implement this.  Otherwise, you have to fetch each image and write them to the device in order to display them in a native Android widget.  There are several ways to approach this, like: http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet4724.htm

You can use `WebView.addJavascriptInterface` to communicate with native code.  A good example can be found in the **WebViewDemo** from the [apps-for-android project](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/) on Google Code.

You might want to consider a framework like [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) to help with the Java to JavaScript interface.